# how to change label type into date type in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i'm trying to convert this string type into date time 
Here :

```
Dim podate As Label = 19/12/2016
Dim datedate As Date = Date.Now
datedate = Convert.ToDateTime(podate).toString("yyyyMMdd")
```

and the result it says : Input string was not in a correct format. any idea where did i wrong?

Comment: The first line won't even compile so what is the actual code you are trying to run? Also if you want to convert String to DateTime use DateTime.Parse and after that you are done, don't try to convert it to String and set that to DateTime-variable (last line of your code).

Comment: @Esko is correct `19/12/2016` instead of `"19/12/2016"` it will result to syntax error what do u need to do? please explain more or else it will result to downvote

Comment: yeah i forgot to input (""), and now i had solution for this one, i convert query date to varchar on my SQL Server. and now i can convert back to date type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
Dim podate as String
Dim podateToString as String

podate = "19/12/2016"
podateToString = podate

podateToString.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```